# How to convert UNICODE / UTF-8 to GB2312 in C

Tags: javascript, c, unicode, utf-8, gb2312

I'm searching for a method to convert a two Byte UNICODE **or** a variable (1-3 Byte) UTF-8 string to Chinese Simplified (GB2312). I found a lot of methods for php, Java, C# and Windows but nothing for standard "C".

Right now, my best solution is to translate this JavaScript example:
https://gist.github.com/19317362/a1d8e40bfb6587463d4d

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a C-compatible library, like [iconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) or [icu](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have never worked with this libraries, so I will check it. But I think there is a lot of overhead... My problem is to implement the functionality to a small embedded cpu.

Comment: Charset processing is not trivial in general. And while UTF-16 and UTF-8 are fairly simple to parse by hand, GB2312 is not so trivial to encode.  So you are better off using an existing library for it. If you want to try writing your own GB3212 encoder from scratch, then read up about ISO/IEC 2022 and its ISO-2022-JP-2 encoding, for instance. Or find a dedicated GB2312 library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Remy Lebeau mentioned, I used the C-compatible library iconv.